# How to program MSI installer to write to registry?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

How to program the MSI installer, to write the user selected installation path to the registry? Later, I want my c++ program to read the path from the registry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an entry in the [Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371168%28VS.85%29.aspx) table with the "Value" field set to [TARGETDIR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372064%28VS.85%29.aspx) property.

Comment: I must code this inside my visual c++ project or in the installer?